# About grep option between two case

Tags: linux, grep, find, directory-structure

I tried to find some text.

What is different between the two below?

```
grep -r "text" ./*
grep -r "text" .
```

Comment: . means current directory
./* means all elements under current directory

the behavior for ls for example will be quite different in the 2 situations, for grep it will be the same since you are using the recursive mode 

if you want to be sure you can just output the result of both commands in 2 different output files and then make a diff between those!

Comment: try `strace` command if you can.

Comment: @Karthikeyan why do you advise use of strace? strace dumps all low-level systems calls for a process. I searched for the use case of strace with grep ... and grep is certainly useful to limit the (often massive) volume of output from strace. Or are you envisioning some other use case?

Comment: Hi @Han. As a new user, remember to accept any answers that you find useful. This will get you reputation points which give you privileges so that you can participate more fully with StackOverflow. ... And I'm impressed that a short user name like Han is still available after many years of SO operating. Good snag!

Comment: @RickMajpruz, reason behind to use `strace` is user can view the arguments that are passing to the grep command.

Answer (score 1):

Both commands get files from the [current directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) and files from lower directories ... but `./*` will exclude any [hidden files and directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) that have a name beginning with `.` such as `~/.bashrc`.

```
grep -r "text" ./*
grep -r "text" .
```

The `-r` flag means to do a recursive search and the `.` means to use the current directory and the `*` means to use all non-hidden-files in the given directory. A recursive search means that every file in this directory and all files in all subdirectories will be handled.

But the seemingly more inclusive `./*` paradoxically misses some files. One key category of files missed are many of the [rc files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_commands) such as ~/.bashrc, if you happened to be searching from a UNIX-like OS from the top level of your user account.

Comment: `./*` or `*` will not match hidden files, `.` will match them.

Comment: Thanks @thanasisp for catching my slip up. Your correction has been incorporated into my answer.